# w command not showing users when not root

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, permissions

I have multiple users logged on my server (ubuntu 12.10), with ssh. None of them has root privileges.

If I log in with my admin account and type

```
w
```

the resulting output is:

```
17:21:05 up 10 days, 18:47,  3 users,  load average: 0,09, 0,09, 0,08
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

Now if I type

```
sudo w
```

the resulting output is:

```
17:22:00 up 10 days, 18:48,  3 users,  load average: 0,04, 0,07, 0,07
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
admin    pts/0    XX.XX.XX.XX      16:15    4.00s  0.34s  0.06s sshd: admin [priv]
user1    pts/1    XX.XX.XX.XX      17:04   17:40   0.17s  0.17s -sh
user2    pts/2    XX.XX.XX.XX      14:31    2:50m  0.16s  0.16s -sh
```

Why is that?

Unrelated question: what does the first line, last column (sshd: admin [priv]) mean in this case? I read it's relative to sshd privilege separation threads, but that's not clear to me what the line precisely means.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is by design, why would you want non-privileged users to be able to spy on other users? even other non-privileged users

Comment: I can't even see my own user session with "w". Shouldn't this display "need root privileges" if it was by design?
Note that "who" has a totally different behavior and allows me to see any connected user, even without sudo.

Comment: `w` shows "who is logged on and what they are doing", while `who` shows "who is logged on". Having a "need root privileges" type error would disrupt proper use of the tool, as unprivileged user X can use it to see if X is logged on more than once.

Comment: Quoting myself: "I can't even see my own user session with "w".". Even if I am logged on multiple times with the same account.
There really is something going wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a security mechanism that doesn't allow w to iterate over /proc/$pid/ and get the information necessary for this. I think the grsecurity kernel hardening does this by default.

Comment: `ps` shows me my own processes but `w` doesn't show anything.
So you mean `w` can't iterate over /proc/$pid (because of a restriction in a kernel patch) but `ps` or a simple `ls /proc/*` can?

Comment: It can only see your own processes in /proc/ in the presence of the grsecurity patch. `w` iterates over the whole process list in my strace of it. Not being able to see other user's processes probably triggers some display bug or the like.